# Last visit page tracking with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, store

I have a vue application and I want somehow save or memorize the last visited page with `vuex-persistentstate`. What I want is: I have 3 pages for example A,B,C and all three leads to Page D and on Page D there is a "cancel/finish" button. Clicking it now, redirect to Home Page. But I want to return  to the last visit page depending where I was (A,B or C).

I want to realize it with `vuex-persistentstate`

So far I have this.

`src/store/index.js`

```
export default createStore({
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      key: 'xx',
      paths: [
        'global.pageAfterFinishClick',
        ...,
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

And here `src/store/global/index.js`

```
state: {
    pageAfterFinishClick: '/'
...
}
```

I think next step is to add mutation and action and update my router?

```
mutations: {
  // Other mutations...
  [SET_PAGE_AFTER_FINISH_CLICK](state, payload) {
    state.pageAfterFinishClick = payload;
  },
}
```

and

```
actions: {
  // Other actions...
  setPageAfterFinishClick({ commit }, page) {
    commit(SET_PAGE_AFTER_FINISH_CLICK, page);
  },
}
```

I'm struggling with this step and need your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it:

Vuex store

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    previousRoute: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setPreviousRoute(state, route) {
      state.previousRoute = route;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    updatePreviousRoute({ commit }, route) {
      commit('setPreviousRoute', route);
    },
  },
});
```

And then I Update `router` setup to dispatch the `updatePreviousRoute` action whenever a route navigation occurs:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Dispatch action to update previous route
  store.dispatch('updatePreviousRoute', from);
  next();
});
```

With this setup, every time a route navigation occurs, the `updatePreviousRoute` action is dispatched with the previous route information, and it updates the Vuex store with the previous route.

And then I use the `previousRoute` property from the `Vuex store` to navigate back:

```
methods: {
  onCancelFinishClick() {
    // Navigate to the previous page
    this.$router.push(this.$store.state.previousRoute || '/');
  },
},
```

This will navigate to the previous page if available, or to the home page ('/') if there is no previous route stored.